# Having a forum in a subfolder

Tags: customization, directory

I have a standard wp site in www.example.com
Also have a smf forum in forum.example.com
What do I need to do to put the forum in www.example.com/forum ?

I guess this involves two parts:

1. redirecting the old urls (which I will ask in a separate question as it is not especially WP related)
2. Setting WP in a way that it will show the forum instead of a "page not found" in the www.example.com/forum address. How can I do this?

Comment: First, which software is used in the forum? Have you moved it already to example.com/forum but it returns 404 status?

Comment: It's smf. I didn't create the folder because I know that WP dynamically creates folders (for categories etc.) So, I don't know where I should create this folder.

Comment: Move your forum first, then come back if WordPress catch the forum requests, which it shouldn't do it. Obviously, if WordPress has some "example.com/forum" URL (for example a page or post called "forum), you will have problems; come back if you have them.